# PySpark geolocation ranking duplicate rows to columns pivot

Tags: loops, pyspark, pivot, pandas-groupby, rank

I have a spark dataframe/table called "df" containing city & postal code combinations along with each city/postal code's geocoordinates. The table also contains geocoordinates for several shops e.g., theater, bar, car shop. The table has hundreds of duplicate rows for each city & postal code combination with each shop and I have calculated the distance of each city & postal code from each shop location in kilometers using the haversine formula. Here's an excerpt of what the table looks like (I've limited the example to just 3 city & postal codes):

```
CITY_POSTAL latitude_CITY_POSTAL    longitude_CITY_POSTAL   location    latitude_location   longitude_location      distance
0         1               7.1899                   52.208    theater              36.8381              -2.4597   6416.753469
1         1               7.1899                   52.208        bar              41.6561              -0.8773   6460.611645
2         1               7.1899                   52.208   car_shop              37.2829              -5.9209   6725.829125
3         2              -5.9209                  37.4827    theater              36.8381              -2.4597   6308.847913
4         2              -5.9209                  37.4827        bar              41.6561              -0.8773   6566.958894
5         2              -5.9209                  37.4827   car_shop              37.2829              -5.9209   6579.375371
6         3              83.1072                   54.849    theater              36.8381              -2.4597   5523.801936
7         3              83.1072                   54.849        bar              41.6561              -0.8773   4974.492016
8         3              83.1072                   54.849   car_shop              37.2829              -5.9209   5516.266902
```

I would now like to groupby and pivot the table such that each unique city & postal code has n-amount of columns ranked from nearest to farthest shop also including a column for the distance of each shop. I've done this using pandas syntax as follows:

```
# Use a Pivot Table to go from long to wide format
df = (
    df.pivot_table(index='CITY_POSTAL',
                    columns=(
                        # Create Groups based on Sorted Distance
                            df3.sort_values('distance', ascending=True)
                            .groupby('CITY_POSTAL').cumcount() + 1
                    ),
                    values=['location', 'distance'],
                    aggfunc='first')
        .sort_index(level=[1, 0], axis=1, ascending=(True, False))
)

# Collapse MultiIndex
df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: '_'.join(map(str, x)))
df = df.reset_index()
```

Which yields the table I'm interested in:

```
   CITY_POSTAL location_1   distance_1 location_2   distance_2 location_3   distance_3
0            1    theater  6416.753469        bar  6460.611645   car_shop  6725.829125
1            2    theater  6308.847913        bar  6566.958894   car_shop  6579.375371
2            3        bar  4974.492016   car_shop  5516.266902    theater  5523.801936
```

I don't know how to write this in PySpark. Can someone please help in making this translation?

Comment: In your input there is no column `distance`.

Comment: I didn’t show the calculation here. I used the haversine formula though.

Answer (score 0):

You can group the dataframe by `CITY_POSTAL`, collect all locations and distances into an array, sort the array by distance and then select the N first elements of the array:

```python
df.groupBy("CITY_POSTAL").agg(F.collect_list(F.struct("location", "distance")).alias("dist")) \
        .withColumn("dist", F.expr("array_sort(dist, (l,r) -> if(l['distance'] < r['distance'],-1,1))")) \
        .selectExpr("CITY_POSTAL", 
                "dist[0]['location'] as locaction_1",
                "dist[0]['distance'] as distance_1",
                "dist[1]['location'] as locaction_2",
                "dist[1]['distance'] as distance_2",
                "dist[2]['location'] as locaction_3",
                "dist[2]['distance'] as distance_3") \
        .show(truncate=False)
```

Output:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|CITY_POSTAL|locaction_1|distance_1 |locaction_2|distance_2 |locaction_3|distance_3 |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|1          |theater    |6416.753469|bar        |6460.611645|car_shop   |6725.829125|
|3          |bar        |4974.492016|car_shop   |5516.266902|theater    |5523.801936|
|2          |theater    |6308.847913|bar        |6566.958894|car_shop   |6579.375371|
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```